# Fixed The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Data'. Try defining the operator '[]'. flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, search

hello I have a problem here, I want to make a search feature in a list, and I try to follow the tutors on the internet and I change the data list to retrieve the list in the API but an error occurs as below.

```
  final List<Data> allData = [];
  // final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allUsers = [];

  // List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundUsers = [];
  List<Data> _foundData = [];

  @override
  initState() {
    _foundData = allData;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Data> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = allData;
    } else {
      results = allData
          .where((user) =>
              user['name'].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }

    setState(() {
      _foundData = results;
    });
  }
```

[image]

```
 TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
```

Comment: `allData` is a list of `Data`. so its not `Map` anymore. idk your `Data` model. but should be `where((user)=>user.name.toLowerCase()` instead?

Comment: The method 'toLowerCase' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: try: `=> (user?.name ?? '').toLowerCase()`

Comment: respon no result found

Comment: there is no error, but the data is not displayed

Comment: try to check the response

Answer (score 0):

```
  results = allData
      .where((user) =>
          user['name'].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
```

What you are actually doing above is finding the Map<String, dynamic>. That's not what you want. Your variable is "user", so I'm inferring that your Data structure is probably an UID-Map<String, dynamic>.  So, if I'm right, and Data is actually a List<String<Map<String, dynamic>>, then you have to get a level deeper.

To give you an idea of the structure, here's a code snippet of what you could be working with:

```
List<Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>> test = [{'123':{'name': 'Joe'}}];
  print(test[0]['123']!['name']);
  
  var something = test.where((map) {
    return map.values.any((innerMap) =>
      innerMap['name'].toLowerCase().contains('joe')
    );                                                  
  }).toList();
  print(something[0]['123']!['name']);
```

If that doesn't help, add the Data structure for your Data to be able to get more specific.